# Upgrading SQL database when the tables have not changed but an insert method has

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I have this SQLite Database class that I am inserting objects to, and I wanted to insert more objects, my current version is one but I know the effect will not be seen unless I upgrade to version 2.

Here

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

// my method

insertItems(db);

}

//where I have my items added
 private void insertItems(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        ArrayList<ExpenseItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

How do I update or upgrade this database? I have tables but the tables are not altered only the method insertItems.

So what do I do here.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // The database is still at version 1, so there's nothing to do be done here.

}
```

Comment: You don't need an upgrade of the database. You will make changes to the SQLiteOpenHelper class, so you need to release a new version of your app. This new version will work with the existing database after the app is installed (upgraded).

Comment: It is not showing, I have tried, it only shows when I work with old items but the new item did not create.

Comment: @forpas what kind of changes? please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You say that you will change a method. This will result to a new version of your application if it is already released. If it is not released then you have nothing to worry about. In any case if you don't make changes to the schema of the db you don't need a db upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is that the call to insert the items is in the **onCreate** method. The **onCreate** method will only ever run automatically once when the database is created. So the code/line `insertItems(db);` will only ever be run once.

You could use **onUpgrade** to execute **insertItems** noting that the code should check the version is being changed from 1 to 2. In which case you could have :-

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
        insertItems(db);
    }
    // The database is still at version 1, so there's nothing to do be done here.
}
```

along with changing the version to 2.

- This assumes

  - that **insertItems** will not add duplicates,
  - that the **onUpgrade** method will not drop the table(s) and call **onCreate** when the version is changed from 1 to 2.

Personally, at this stage, then simply uninstalling the app and rerunning may suffice (assuming the new items are added to the insert code, rather than replacing the insert code and that other existing data, if any, can be lost or will be recreated).